# Bitwise NOT on hexadecimal numbers in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a long string containing hexadecimal numbers. What's the best way to replace each number with its [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_complement#NOT) (also in hex)?

That is, if I have

```
$string = "d3e5d1b8 66300f40 16010f2e \ncc1e010f 00b0b802 bbd0000f e38e0098 \n"
```

I want to get

```
$string = "2b1a2e47 99bff0cf e9fef0d1 \n33e1fef0 ff4f47fd 442ffff0 1b71ff67 \n";
```

The solution I have right now is doing a substitution for each of the 16 hex digits

```
$string=~s/0/g/g; $string=~s/f/0/g; $string=~s/g/f/g;
...
...
16 times
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "invert"; what's your expected output?

Comment: Zeros become ones in the hex string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [tr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cds):

```
$string =~ tr/0123456789abcdef/fedbca9876543210/;
```

Comment: Until my edit is approved note that the second string 'fedbca9876543210' should be 'fedcba9876543210'

Answer (score 1):

Fixed typo:
$string =~ tr/0123456789abcdef/fed**cb**a9876543210/;

Comment: To specify a correction you can add this as a comment rather than a new answer.